# Error: GPIO #num# is not enabled for pi-blaster

Tags: gpio, pwm

I currently have a project where I need to be able to use 12 GPIOs to control lights.  I'm using pi-blaster for my PWM needs, and it works great where it works, but some GPIOs it throws no error when registering, but does return an error upon changing `GPIO #num# is not enabled for pi-blaster`

Here's a list of GPIOs in regards to enabled and banned.

> all :: [17,18,16,19,13,20,12,21,6,22,5,23,4,24,25,26,27]
>
> banned :: [6,]
>
> non banned :: [17,18,16,19,13,20,12,21,22,5,23,4,24,25,26,27]
>
> non enabled :: [16,19,13,20,12,5,26]
>
> enabled :: [17,18,21,22,23,24,4,25,27]

Using `$ pi-blaster --gpio 17,18,16,19,13,20,12,21,22,5,23,4,24,25,26,27` for all non-banned GPIOs neither solves the problem nor throws an error.

How can I expand the set of enabled GPIOs to include at least 12 of the non-banned GPIOs, or is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:  `sudo` must be used for some of the GPIOs, but not all.

To solve, simply add `sudo`

`$ sudo pi-blaster --gpio 17,18,16,19,13,20,12,21,22,5,23,4,24,25,26,27`

Comment: Why do you think 16 is the maximum?  The Pi3 has 26 accessible GPIO.  pigpio will provide PWM on all of them.

Comment: You're right.  It's just my breakout board.